# QPushButton keeps increasing in size

Tags: qt

I'm trying to display a captured image from a webcam on a button. The problem is every time I capture a new image the size of the button increases. Here is the code:

```
connect(imageCapture, SIGNAL(imageCaptured(int,QImage)), this, SLOT(processCapturedImage(int,QImage)));
.
.
.
.

void Camera::processCapturedImage(int requestId, const QImage& img)
{
    Q_UNUSED(requestId);
    QImage scaledImage = img.scaled(ui->lastImageCapturedBtn->size(),
                                Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    QPixmap capturedImage = QPixmap::fromImage(scaledImage);
    ui->lastImageCapturedBtn->setIcon(QIcon(capturedImage));
    ui->lastImageCapturedBtn->setIconSize(capturedImage.rect().size());
}
```

I changed

```
QImage scaledImage = img.scaled(ui->lastImageCapturedBtn->size(),
                                Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                Qt::SmoothTransformation);`
```

to `QImage scaledImage = img.scaled(298,298);` which had no effect, with every click of to capture a new image the button gets bigger and bigger.

I also changed the line

```
ui->lastImageCapturedBtn->setIconSize(capturedImage.rect().size());
```

to

```
ui->lastImageCapturedBtn->setIconSize(ui->lastImageCapturedBtn->size());
```

- again the same behavior

The button was created using Qt Designer. I change the maximumSize to 298x298 and iconSize to 298x298

Comment: Did you debug the size values? Is the size of `capturedImage` the same each time?

Comment: why you don't set it a maximum size ?

Comment: How about QWidget::setFixedSize() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the minimumSize to 298x298 and now it's working the way I intended